# Tracking A/B Test Marketing cloud in Sales

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, marketingcloudapi, sales, email-tracking

We have done some A/B testing and we have not been able to generate any kind of object in Sales like the IndividualEmailResult of the normal mailings.

I don't know if there is any way to collect this information in an object, as the most I have found is the page where you can see the tracking(https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_track_ab_test_results.htm&type=5).

And the truth is that we would like to have this information in Sales to be able to work with it.

Is there any way to make this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your A/B test in Salesforce Marketing Cloud, making sure to use unique tracking URLs for each test group.

Connect Salesforce Marketing Cloud to Salesforce CRM using Marketing Cloud Connect. This will allow you to automatically sync data between the two platforms.

In Salesforce CRM, create a custom object to store your A/B test data. You can do this by going to Setup > Object Manager > Create > Custom Object. Choose a name for your object and add any custom fields you want to track.

Use Marketing Cloud Connect to map your A/B test data to your custom object in Salesforce. You can do this by going to the Marketing Cloud tab in Salesforce and selecting "Data Sources". Choose your A/B test data and map it to your custom object fields.

Once your A/B test is complete, you can view the results in your custom object in Salesforce. You can use this data to analyze the effectiveness of your email campaigns and make data-driven decisions to optimize your email marketing strategy.